# range() integer end argument expected, got Tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, iteration

I'm trying to write a for loop to go through a HTML table consisting of `th` and `td` tags. It's contained in the URL:

```
https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=edinburgh%2C+GOGARBANK%2C+EDINBURGH%2C+Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&x=16&y=8&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=GOGARBANK%2C+EDINBURGH%2C+Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=GOGARBANK&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL&UARN=103G494E2%28B%29&PPRN=000000000000532&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&#results'
```

I think `th` is for table heading and I'd like to extract the `td` (table data). The `for` loops I am trying to use are giving me an error:

```
range() integer end argument expected, got Tag.
```

Can someone explain to me why please? The output I want is

```
103G494E2(B)(LOTHIAN VJB)
YARD
```

I've also tried using the
`for i in range(len(elems)):`

but its given me an error `object of type 'int' has no len()`. Is the `i` in this case being defined as an integer by using the range function? This method has worked for me before so not really sure why it doen't this time. many thanks.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

url = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk/search.php?SEARCHED=1&SEARCH_TABLE=valuation_roll_cpsplit&SEARCH_TERM=edinburgh%2C+GOGARBANK%2C+EDINBURGH%2C+Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&x=16&y=8&DISPLAY_COUNT=10&ASSESSOR_ID=&TYPE_FLAG=CP&ORDER_BY=PROPERTY_ADDRESS&H_ORDER_BY=SET+DESC&DRILL_SEARCH_TERM=GOGARBANK%2C+EDINBURGH%2C+Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&DD_UNITARY_AUTHORITY=Edinburgh%2C+City+Of&DD_TOWN=EDINBURGH&DD_STREET=GOGARBANK&DISPLAY_MODE=FULL&UARN=103G494E2%28B%29&PPRN=000000000000532&ASSESSOR_IDX=10&#results'
baseurl = 'https://www.saa.gov.uk'

session = requests.session()

response = session.get(url)

# content of search page in soup 
html = soup(response.content,"lxml")
# list of result entries
rslt_table = html.find("table", {"summary":"Property details"})

ref = 'n/a'
vsr = 'n/a'

for col in rslt_table:
    elems = col.find("th")
    data = col.find("td")
    #for i in range(len(elems)):
    for i in range(elems):
        if elems [i].text == "Ref No. / Office":
            ref = data[i].text
            print ref
        if elems [i].text == 'Description':
            vsr = data[i].text
            print vsr
```

Comment: in addition to what wpercy said, you might be using the wrong method. From the bs4 docs: ```The only difference is that find_all() returns a list containing the single result, and find() just returns the result.```

So you might want to try using find_all()

Comment: all these `find`s should be `find_all`s!

Comment: thanks, I used the enumerate line as suggest by wpercy and put elems = col.find_all("th") but got an attribute error AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: Boom - thank you. changed the rslt_table = html to a find_all also and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use range, you should be using `enumerate()` just use `for i,elem in enumerate(elems)` and then check against `elem` instead of `elems[i]`. Using `enumerate` allows you to also keep track of the index so you can access the correct elements in `data`.

That for loop would look like this:

```
for col in rslt_table:
    elems = col.find_all("th")
    data = col.find_all("td")
    for i,elem in enumerate(elems):
        if elem.text == "Ref No. / Office":
            ref = data[i].text
            print ref
        if elem.text == 'Description':
            vsr = data[i].text
            print vsr
```

You should also use `find_all()` instead of `find()` to get a list of items, not just the single one. So your `rslt_table` should look like:

```
rslt_table = html.find_all("table", {"summary":"Property details"})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm still getting an integer error however

Comment: for i,elem in enumerate(elems):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

You're making several mistakes. First of all, find returns a single element - to get a collection of elements, you must use find_all everywhere. range doesn't take an element, nor a list; use enumerate() or range(len()).

Fixed code would be

```
rslt_table = html.find_all("table", {"summary":"Property details"})

for col in rslt_table:
    elems = col.find_all("th")
    data = col.find_all("td")
    for i, e in enumerate(elems):
        if e.text == "Ref No. / Office":
            ref = data[i].text
            print(ref)
        if e.text == 'Description':
            vsr = data[i].text
            print(vsr)
```